# How is it possible that performance.navigationStart is the same as performance.loadEventEnd?

Tags: javascript

I am running some timing metrics and in some very infrequent loads, my performance.navigationStart is the same as my performance.loadEventEnd  -- How is this possible?

Any ideas?

At the top of the page, I call this performance timing item: navigationStart, and then when page loads, I call : loadEventEnd.

In most cases, they are different and I can generate a load time. BUT, in a small amount of cases, they are the same value. Why would this happen?

Comment: You'd need to add more detail to the question if you want an answer.

Comment: In those cases the browser has already cached everything on that page? Try checking the "Network" tab of your dev tools to see what all is loading from cache (and not).